# Python socket error 10061 - connection refused

Tags: python, sockets

This is a host and guest program using python socket

```
import socket

running = True


host_guest = int(input("Select Host Or Guest : "))
port = int(input("Write Port : "))

#Host
if host_guest == 0:
    client_socket = []
    player_count = int(input("Write Player Count : "))

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('', port))
    server_socket.listen(player_count)

    while running:
        command = input("Write Command : ")
        if command == "Wait For Player":
            client_information = server_socket.accept()
            client_socket.append(client_information[0])

            print("Connected From : " + str(client_information[0]))
            print("Player Port : " + str(client_information[1]))

        elif command == "Send Message":
            message = input("Write Messege : ")
            server_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            print("Sended")

        elif command == "Recive Message":
            message = server_socket.recv(1024)
            print(message)

        elif command == "Close":
            server_socket.close()
            running = False

#Guest
elif host_guest == 1:
    host_ip = input("Write Host IP : ")

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((host_ip, port))

    while running:
        if command == "Send Message":
            message = input("Write Messege : ")
            server_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            print("Sended")

        elif command == "Recive Message":
            message = server_socket.recv(1024)
            print(message)
            
        elif command == "Close":
            server_socket.close()
            running = False
```

I ran the above program and I got error 10061.
So I looked for a solution, and they said it would be solved by running each program on a different IDLE.
But that didn't solve it.

What is the solution to this problem?